# props-dependent Switch color in Material-UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, uiswitch

The following code, adapted from Material-UI docs for [customizing `Switch`](https://material-ui.com/fr/components/switches/#customized-switches) allows to set the switch color to blue:

```js
import React from 'react'

import Switch from '@material-ui/core/Switch'
import {withStyles} from '@material-ui/core/styles'


const ColoredSwitch = withStyles({
  switchBase: {
    '&$checked': {
      color: 'blue',
    },
  },
  checked: {},
  track: {},
})(Switch)
```

[image: Blue switch]

But when trying to adapt it so that the color can be set by component properties, it just doesn't work. Event the following code (which is only pseudo-dynamic) renders to a default switch:

```js
const ColoredSwitch = withStyles({
  switchBase: {
    '&$checked': {
      color: props => 'blue',
    },
  },
  checked: {},
  track: {},
})(Switch)
```

[image: Default switch]

I guess I must be doing something wrong but can't figure out what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this example for passing props if you must use `withStyles` HOC: https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#adapting-the-higher-order-component-api

```
const ColoredSwitch = withStyles({
  switchBase: {
    "&.Mui-checked": {
      color: (props) => props.customchecked
    }
  },
  checked: {},
  track: {}
})((props) => {
  const { classes, ...other } = props;
  return <Switch classes={{ switchBase: classes.switchBase }} {...other} />;
});
```

[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]

---

You can also use `makeStyles`

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  switchBaseChecked: {
    "&.Mui-checked": {
      color: (props) => props.color
    }
  }
});

export default function Switches() {
  const props = { color: "green" };
  const classes = useStyles(props);
  return (
    <Switch
      color="primary"
      classes={{
        checked: classes.switchBaseChecked
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]

Comment: Thanks, it does fix my problem. Do you have any explanation though on why my solution did not work? I don't understand why changing `color: 'blue` to `color: props => 'blue'` breaks the code. Isn't it the way `withStyles` usually works?

Comment: The docs you referenced did not contain any information regarding adapting based on props so I took a look at the document I referenced. However, the main issue seems to have been with referencing the local rule name `checked` when you are using props. In fact, if you replace `&$checked` with `&.Mui-checked` in your implementation, it should work. I've primarily used `makeStyles` for styling components (when using MUI) - I overlooked my example with that regard and made edits to my answer to demonstrate passing props using `makeStyles`.